# How can I find the current apps name from python on heroku?

Tags: python, heroku

How can I find the current apps name from python on heroku? I want to know, because I'm using the heroku button to start and instance automatically. Can it be made part of os.environ somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via Heroku support:

> Finding the app's name is not something currently possible to do,
>   sorry. The only thing you can potentially do is to analyse the
>   hostname requests are coming from and deduce the app's name with it.